# How do I connect Komodo to my sql server

Tags: mysql, virtualbox, ubuntu-12.04, komodo

I wonder if someone help me, this is my set up:

I am on a windows 7 machine running a ubuntu virtualbox as my local web server and database server (mysql).

I have just got hold of a copy of Komodo which i am running on my windows machine which I would like to hook up to my database. The fields it needs are hostname, port, socket, username and password.

I know the username/password but am unsure how to find out what to put for the other fields. The ubuntu vb has an ip of 192.168.0.10, which is in my hosts file as http://swishprint.dev

I hope I have asked this in the right place, any help much appreciated.

Comment: The [MySQL admin](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/MySQL/Administration) wiki may help.